# ASP.NET Core: A dependency package was not found in the production

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core project targeting .NET Core 2.0. The problem is that when I publish my project to IIS (through Visual Studio Publish Wizard) server and browser the site I face with below error page.

[image: IIS Site 502 error]

I enabled error logs and found below error in the logs:

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (RubyVAS.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery', version: '2.0.1'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'

  This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the application was published using the following target manifest files:
    aspnetcore-store-2.0.3.xml
```

Also here is the same problem as me, but none of the solutions worked.

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/13542

But when I publish it with `dotnet publish` the error disappears but another strange thing happens. That is the `[Authorize]` filter stops working in this case. That means I can browse all controller actions as anonymous without login, while it should redirect me to login page. However this works without any problem when I run the project from within the Visual Studio. I have searched a lot for this problem and it is not a mis-configuration in my `startup.cs`.

I hope someone would know what is going on here?

Comment: For the first error, did you check whether that DLL exists? Also, can you add which steps did you actually follow from the GitHub issue?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto
1. Added this to .csproj:
`<PropertyGroup>
 <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup>`
2. Published with `dotnet publish` command. This solves the first error. But the `authorize` filter will not work in the published site.
3. Made sure that both environments have the same dotnet version

Comment: Did you install ASP.NET Core on the deployment target?  Seems like you didn't. That's the error you get when you try to deploy an application without the correct version of the framework installed on the other side.

Comment: Did you try upgrading your ASP.NET Core SDK?  https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows

Comment: Also, did you try fixing your reply URLs? (Assuming you are using Azure AD Authentication?)

Comment: @Taraz Thanks. The problem solved. I added `<PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>` to the `.csproj` and also updated the ASP.NET Core Hosting SDK and it solved. However I don't know what that property mean anyway :)